# YouTubeのようなGoodとBadの作り方

Tags: mysql, pdo

データベースで独自の投票パーツを作ったのですが、1アクセスごとにSELECT文で結果の数
（83good 12bad）を取得していてはデータベースサーバに負担が大きいのですが、このような簡易データベースにキャッシュなどのやり方は存在しますか？

Comment: 動画毎に、GoodとBadの総数持たせてやれば良いだけの話のような気がします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

一般的には非正規化を行います。
「ユーザーID, good/bad」のようなユーザー毎のデータを持つテーブルと、「goodCount, badCount」のような回数を集計したテーブルの二つのテーブルを作成します。そして整合性を壊さないように二つのテーブルを更新するようにします。

Answer (score 2):

おそらく誰がいつvoteしたとかの情報は必要だろうと想像してその前提であれば、集計クエリを何らかの方法でキャッシュするのが一般的です。

- アプリケーションのローカルメモリ
- memcachedなどのインメモリKVS
- Redis等永続化可能なKVS
- PostgreSQLの場合、pgpoolというミドルウェアがありクエリキャッシュ機能があります
- MySQLは自分自身でクエリキャッシュ機能を持っています
- RDBMSの別テーブルをキャッシュとして使う

など方法はいろいろあります。

- データの整合性保証
- 要求されるパフォーマンス
- キャッシュが空の状態での性能低下防止(ウォームアップ)

など、検討すべきポイントはいろいろありますが、環境や背景が何も書かれていないので、具体的にどうすべきかはなんとも言えません。